# How to Store a Mixed Array in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, arrays

I need to store two types of objects, `Feed` and `Folder`, in an array in Core Data. For example:

```
Array
    Feed
    Feed
    Folder
    Feed
    Folder
    Folder
    …etc...
```

I know about [`BWOrderedManagedObject`](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/blog/2008/per-object-ordered-relationships-using-core-data) for storing objects in order in Core Data, but I'm not sure how to store mixed objects (the array needs to be mixed, since the items are in a specific order). Ideally, I'd have a relationship that pointed to two entities, but obviously this isn't possible.

The only solution I can see is to make the array a `Transformable` attribute. However, what about the objects stored within the array? Will I need to manage all of them myself or will they still be managed by Core Data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I've done it:

[alt text http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Screen%20shot%202010-07-06%20at%207.22.10%20PM/web.png?ver=12784658050001](http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Screen%20shot%202010-07-06%20at%207.22.10%20PM/web.png?ver=12784658050001)

`AbstractListItem` is an abstract entity that has the order property and a relationship to a `Folder`, which indicates the item's (single) parent.

`Folder` is a concrete child of `AbstractListItem` that has a to-many relationship to `AbstractListItem`, which means the folder can have as many children as it wants that are `AbstractListItems` (so either `Folders` or `Feeds`).

`Feeds` aren't anything special, except that they also inherit from `AbstractListItem` (meaning that they have an order and a parent, and can be children of a `Folder`).

So once you have a folder, you can get all of its children in order by doing something like:

```
NSArray * orderedChildren = [[aFolder children] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES]]];
```

To get your top-level items, you'd execute a fetch looking for all `AbstractListItem` objects where `parent = nil`.